# Python max() function & Project Euler No 4

Tags: python

When I try to solve Project Euler Problem No 4, I wrote the code :

```
l=[]
for i in range(100,1000):
    for j in range (100,1000):

        a=i*j
        b=str(a)
        if b==b[::-1]:
           l.append(b)
print(max(l[-10:]))
```

the answer is 906609. But when I wrote instead of `max(l[-10:])`, `max(l)` the outcome became 99999. 
The question is, however, the numbers in the list are same, but why the *max* outcome is different?

Comment: When i executed the above code with max(l[-10:]), i got 906609

Comment: execute code via max(l).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting not `int` max is because the comparison is between strings. You are appending strings to the list.

Replace

```
l.append(b)
```

with

```
l.append(a)
```

to get the expected output.

Comment: How can I reverse a variable without changing the type to string?

Comment: @PervizMamedov what you are doing logically is correct. Just append `a` which is an `int` to the list instead of `b` which is `str` equivalent of `a`. If you want a logic of reversing `int`, that would require some looping logic.

Comment: I have missed that .. Thanks. It was helpfull.